# vlfeat-0.9.19/toolbox/mex/mexa64/libvl.so: undefined symbol: GOMP_parallel

Tags: matlab, makefile, vlfeat

I have compiled vlfeat on linux (archlinux ) with making mex for matlab by the following command

```
make MEX=MATLABROOT/bin/mex
```

in the VLFEATROOT directory. Output seem well as no error was reported. BTW, I use gcc4.7 to compile the stuff above.

I execute the very simple code in my matlab:

```
VLFEATROOT = '~/user-libs/vlfeat/vlfeat-0.9.19/';
path_vlfeat = [VLFEATROOT 'toolbox/vl_setup'];
run(path_vlfeat);
vl_version;
```

the matlab report the following red lines:

```
Invalid MEX-file '/home/bingqingqu/user-libs/vlfeat/vlfeat-0.9.19/toolbox/mex/mexa64/vl_version.mexa64':
/home/bingqingqu/user-libs/vlfeat/vlfeat-0.9.19/toolbox/mex/mexa64/libvl.so: undefined symbol: GOMP_parallel
```

I dont know much about openmp but it seems this is related to that. I noticed that in the makefile of vlfeat there is an option for switching off openmp:

```
# DISABLE_OPENMP=yes
```

and I set it to "yes", compiling and run the simple code. Everything above can execute without error now.

But I want to know what is the problem if I leave the option to no. The makefile comment says:

```
# If defined to anything other than "no", the following falgs disable
# specific features in the library. By defaults, all the features are
# enabled.  If the makefile finds that the environment is unable to
# support some of them, it may decide to disable them automatically
# (in this case it will print a message).  This behaviour can be
# overriden by defining the flag to be "no".
```

I briefly search for some openmp knowledge on google and it seem that all my openmp or gomp are installed fine. see below:
     ldconfig -p | grep gomp
the result is :

```
libgomp.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgomp.so.1
libgomp.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libgomp.so.1
libgomp.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgomp.so
libgomp.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libgomp.so
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following fix:
https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/pull/94